# Datos entre activitys usando spiners

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-spinner

Me gustaría saber como hacer que un Spinner vuelva a cargar los datos que tenia cuando vuelvo de otro Activity. Tengo una actividad tipo habitaciones que al seleccionar una "habitacion" me carga otra ventana donde con spinners registro lo que pedira pero al regresar al pestaña de control se borran las selecciones de los spinners cuando vuelvo para revisar, quisiera saber como mantener los datos de varios spinners cuando cambio de pantallas y no se borren.

por cierto trabajo con kotlin

//////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package com.example.chickenandmoo

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Switch
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn)
    val lista=resources.getStringArray(R.array.Menu)
    val adaptador = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lista)
    spinner.adapter = adaptador


    val r = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn1)
    val lis=resources.getStringArray(R.array.Desayunos)
    val ada = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lis)
    r.adapter = ada

    val n = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn2)
    val l = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Comidas)
    val adap = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,l)
    n.adapter = adap

    val sp = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn3)
    val liste=resources.getStringArray(R.array.Cenas)
    val ad = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,liste)
    sp.adapter = ad


    val rr = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn4)
    val liss=resources.getStringArray(R.array.Bebidas)
    val adaa = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,liss)
    rr.adapter = adaa

    val nn = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spn5)
    val ll = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Bebidas)
    val adapp = 
    ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ll)
    nn.adapter = adapp

    val boton1=findViewById<Button>(R.id.button21)
    boton1.setOnClickListener {
        val intento1 = Intent(this, habitaciones::class.java)
        startActivity(intento1)
            }

    val switc = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.block)
    switc.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        spinner.isEnabled = !isChecked
        r.isEnabled = !isChecked
        n.isEnabled = !isChecked
        sp.isEnabled = !isChecked
        rr.isEnabled = !isChecked
        nn.isEnabled = !isChecked
    }

    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Este es mi codigo donde tengo los spinners con datos que no quiero que se cambien y acontinuacion el codigo donde solo cambio de ventanas con botones

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package com.example.chickenandmoo

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class habitaciones : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_habitaciones)

    val boton1=findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    boton1.setOnClickListener {
        val intento1 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intento1)
    }
    val boton2=findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    boton2.setOnClickListener {
        val intento1 = Intent(this, hab1::class.java)
        startActivity(intento1)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste.

Comment: Hola. Tendrías que implementar [**persistencia de datos**](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/unit-6?hl=es-419) sea mediante una base de datos (Room), mediante DataStore, mediante archivos, etc. Lo más usado en la actualidad son los dos primeros, y todo depende también de la cantidad de datos que quieras guardar.